# xcode storyboard IOS 5.0 switch from a view to another one from login page to an Message page

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, storyboard

I am trying to switch from a login (view) to a (messages) view.

1. I created the two views controllers in the storyboard
2. I created a button (login) in the first view
3. I created a method (loginPressed) and I related the button login with the method
4. Finally I created a segue between the two views from the button login Identifier :"goToMessages" and style "push" to the view Messages graphically.
5. I wrote the code below in the method loginPressed :

   [self.navigationController preformSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToMessages" sender:self];

Is this method wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I always use "self" as follows.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToMessages" sender:self];
```

Also be sure that you have a navigation controller in your project. If you do, then make sure that the segue is configured as a "Push" by selecting the segue and using the attributes inspector to check the "Style". If you don't have a navigation controller select a "Style" of "Modal". Because you need to set the type of segue, storyboard can figure out to use the navigation controller on its own so it does not need to be specified in the statement that invokes the segue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong (in the sense that it's valid code) but it is unnecessary. You can do the whole thing without code.

You create the two view controllers. Add the button to the first. Create the segue from the button to the second view controller.

That's it.

When you run the project, pressing the button will move from the first controller to the second.

Answer (score 0):

If your segue is going to be dependent on if they logged in correctly or not, create your segue by dragging from the view controller to the other, not from the button.
Then call the segue as you have.